# MySQL Stored Procedure, cursor not open (1326)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

So, I am trying to get some result out about a SELECT request but every time I try to call the procedure it gives me :

```
mysql> call canIDoThisSequenceSire(38,18);
ERROR 1326 (24000): Cursor is not open
```

And I have no idea why, I think my cursor is open correctly (I have used this kind of code skeletton (got from here) on other stores procedures and it worked fine) and after trying to find someone with a similar error, I only got people who didn't use the OPEN curl line.

Here is the code

```
PROCEDURE `canIDoThisSequenceSire`(in idOpe INT, in idSeq INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT default FALSE;
DECLARE isRoot,seqParent, seqDone INT;


DECLARE curl CURSOR FOR SELECT 
    se.isRoot, se.id_sequenceEnchainement
    FROM 
        tachesrealisees as tr
    JOIN
        collectiontache as ct
    ON
        ct.id = tr.id_collectiontache
    JOIN
        tache as t
    ON
        t.id=ct.id_tache
    JOIN 
        sequences as s
    ON 
        s.id = ct.id_sequences
    JOIN
        sequenceenchainement as se
    ON
        se.id_sequence=s.id
    WHERE 
        tr.id_operationsrealisees=idOpe
    AND 
        s.id=idSeq;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN curl;


laBoucle : LOOP
    FETCH curl INTO isRoot, seqParent;
    IF isRoot THEN
        SET done = TRUE;
        LEAVE laBoucle;
    END IF;

    IF ISNULL(isRoot) then
        LEAVE laBoucle;
    END IF;

    CLOSE curl;

    END LOOP laBoucle;

    IF done THEN -- La séquence est à la racine
        SELECT 1 as result; 
    END IF;

    IF NOT done THEN 
            SELECT 0 as result; -- Please, come again
    END IF;

END
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the cursor within the LOOP.

```sql
...
    IF ISNULL(isRoot) THEN
        LEAVE laBoucle;
    END IF;
    -- CLOSE curl;
END LOOP laBoucle;
CLOSE curl;
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel really dumb ^^'